# Google Search Appliance sort by metadata content

Tags: google-search-appliance

I'm trying to refine the search results received by my application by including the `sort` parameter in my HTTP requests. I've combed through the documentation [here](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/request_format.html?sa=X&ved=0CB0Q9QEwA2oVChMI-Lyums_2xgIVZSZyCh1ULQXW#1078040), but I can't find exactly what I'm looking for.

I'm searching for `DOC` filetypes, and I am able to `sort` by date or `sort` by metadata, as in alphabetizing by title, author, etc. I can also `filter` by whether or not the title contains certain keywords. What I want to do is to `sort` by whether or not the title contains certain keywords (these documents appearing first in the results), but to **still keep the other results**.

For example, with keywords `[winter, Christmas, holiday]` I could do a `descending sort` by the sum of `inmeta:title~winter`, `inmeta:title~Christmas`, `inmeta:title~holiday` and the top result might be

> Winter holidays other than Christmas

followed by documents with one or two of the keywords, followed by documents that meet the other search parameters but contain no keywords.

Is this possible in GSA?

Answer (score 0):

I finally achieved what I was trying to do, so figured I'd post in case it helps anyone else.

As far as I know, it is impossible to create a *query* with this capability, but with Google's Custom Search API, you can create a search engine with the desired keywords in the context file (by editing the XML file directly or by adding keywords through the CSE console). Then you can formulate the query as usual, but perform the search on your personalized engine.

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/ranking